# getting invalid use of group function when using on duplicate

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a table from a temp table and get the error invalid use of group function. If I take away the on duplicate key update part it doesn't give that error. I am not sure what to do here

```
insert Finalized_Data.Transaction_Details(Store,Ticket,SalespersonCode,ArchSupportsSold,class) 
select Store,Ticket,SalespersonCode,count(class),class 
FROM POS_Data_Import.auto_import_ExportPurchaseDetails as example
group by store,ticket,substring(class,0,7) 
having class like 'ARCH SUPPORTS%'
on duplicate key update ArchSupportsSold=count(example.class);
```

Comment: you have to group by `salespersoncode` and `class` as well as they are in your select statement.  mySQL extends the group by so you don't always have to group by everythgin in your select; but it assumes  those elements not grouped; all have the same value; which doesn't appear to be the case here.  See docs for more inf:o https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: i cannot group by those as grouping by the substring im using is what i need in order to make the count accurate

Comment: Food for thought: Wouldn't the counts by salespersoncode/class be potentially wrong then as the group by will only be by store, ticket and the first 8 characters of the class.  For the counts to be right, salespersoncode, class would have to be the SAME for each substring(Class,0,7) if they aren't your counts would be wrong.  So is it working because you're lucky and such  data just doesn't happen to exist yet?

Answer (score 3):

You can only use aggregation functions in the `SELECT()` query. There's no aggregation going on in the `INSERT` query itself.

If you want to get the  value that would have been inserted into the column if there were no duplicate, use the `VALUES()` function:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ArchSupportsSold = VALUES(ArchSupportsSold)
```

The `VALUES()` function is deprecated in MySQL 8.0.20 (see the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)). Starting in this version you should use a subquery to assign a column alias, and refer to that.

```
insert Finalized_Data.Transaction_Details(Store,Ticket,SalespersonCode,ArchSupportsSold,class) 
SELECT * FROM (
    select Store,Ticket,SalespersonCode,count(class) AS newSold ,class 
    FROM POS_Data_Import.auto_import_ExportPurchaseDetails as example
    group by store,ticket,substring(class,0,7) 
    having class like 'ARCH SUPPORTS%'
) AS x
on duplicate key update ArchSupportsSold = newSold;
```

Comment: the valuefunction is going away though

Comment: @jbigs89 That's annoying. I've updated the answer to show the new way to do it.

Comment: the values() function does still work, they are just warning that it won't at some point.

Comment: @ysth Of course, that's what "deprecated" means.